# assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c, matriz, struct

Estou com um erro ao associar um endereço de uma matriz em um ponteiro para struct, estou recebendo um erro do tipo:

> assignment to expression with array type

O código que estou utilizando é esse:

```
struct MaxHeap
{
    int size;
    int* array;
};

struct MaxHeap* createAndBuildHeap(char array[][25], int size)
    int i;
    struct MaxHeap* maxHeap =
          (struct MaxHeap*) malloc(sizeof(struct MaxHeap));
    maxHeap->size = size;   // initialize size of heap
    maxHeap->array = array; // Assign address of first element of array

    // Start from bottommost and rightmost internal mode and heapify all
    // internal modes in bottom up way
    for (i = (maxHeap->size - 2) / 2; i >= 0; --i)
        maxHeapify(maxHeap, i);
    return maxHeap;
```

Comment: Coloque o código como texto e formate-o com o botão `{}`. Aproveite e inclua também a definição da estrutura `maxHeap` e a chamada ao `createAndBuildHeap`

Answer (score 1):

Quando tenta passar o array para a nova estrutura alocada:

```
maxHeap->array = array; // Assign address of first element of array
```

O tipo do `maxHeap->array` não joga com o tipo do `array` da função.

Ora repare nos dois atentamente:

```
struct MaxHeap
{
    int size;
    int* array;
};//^
//  ^ int* aqui --------------------------- char[][] aqui 
//                                        v
struct MaxHeap* createAndBuildHeap(char array[][25], int size)
```

Ou seja está a tentar colocar um `char[][]` num `int*`.

Pelo que indicou nos comentários, pretende usar o heap para nomes, então deve alterar a estrutura do mesmo para `char **`, o tipo apropriado para isso:

```
struct MaxHeap
{
    int size;
    char **array; //agora o tipo correto para os nomes
};
```

Comment: Desculpa, o certo seria, struct MaxHeap
{
    int size;
    char array[10][25];
};
e mesmo assim continuo com o erro

Comment: @Vitor continua a ser o mesmo erro, `char[][]` não pode ser atribuído a um campo do tipo `int*`. O fato de ter dimensões não modifica em nada o problema

Comment: mas array é um campo char[][], e estou tentando atribuir a maxHeap->array o endereço do primeiro elemento de array[][25] q é parametro na função. array é do tipo char[][] porque tenho uma lista de nomes e tenho q ordena-los alfabeticamente usando heap sort

Comment: @Vitor continua a não poder atribuir arrays de strings a arrays de números. Talvez queira fazer um heap de strings mudando o tipo da estrutura para `char **array` mas isso complicar consideravelmente a implementação do heapify. Independentemente disso, um dos dois terá que ser trocado